# Different DNS servers for different browsers

Tags: browser, dns

On the same Windows XP PC, is it possible to set up different DNS servers for different browsers? How?

I want to use a DNS server for Firefox, another one for Internet Explorer and another one for Chrome.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: "Why would you want to do that? – Rowland Shaw Sep 19 '09 at 18:35" - @Rowland Shaw - Privacy for different profiles or activities on the one computer, or other tricks like doing DNS overseas Netflix unblocking (tunlr) for one specific browser, while enjoying Google's fast DNS for general web browsing in another.

Comment: @RowlandShaw we want to do that because.. when i connected to my work vpn, it uses the work dns to access workplace sites. however, when i browse normal websites, the work dns is very slow to respond, like 20seconds to take me to the site. after i disconnect vpn, the dns behaves normally. this is for me the reason to have different dns under different chrome profile (preferably), or at least on different browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the closest would be to point them to differing proxy servers, which in turn use the differing DNS servers.